# must to do modprob -v rtl8188ee every time i start linux

Tags: networking, drivers

Good afternoon, I'm having a wi-fi problem: my wi-fi signal was poor so I tried to install ndiwrapper to install windows drivers. It did not work so I purged ndiswrapper after uninstall the windows driver installed. Now, to connect my laptop to my wi-fi network I always have to do:

```
sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

why am I having this problem?
thank's for answer this question.

Comment: Remove ndiswrapper and remoce the `rtl8188ee` from blacklist.

Comment: I removed ndiwrapper and rtl8188ee is not in the blacklist.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Did you install any linux drivers from source or from a PPA?

Comment: I did not install any linux drivers... I just try to install the windows drivers with ndiswrapper. I think that rtl8188ee driver is the default driver installed when I installed the OS

Comment: Please add output of `grep rtl8188ee /etc/modprobe.d/*` command.

Comment: that command returns empty

Comment: Try to run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot.

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add rtl8188ee to /etc/modules, and it'll load the driver for you at boot time. Cheers, Al

Comment: Glad it helped. Please rate my solution by clicking the up arrow on the left side of my answer. Cheers, Al